# Which other manifestations of god Vishnu besides Parshurama, are associated with the 'Akshaya-Tritya'?

Tags: vishnu, panchang, nara-narayana, tithi

The third lunar day of the bright fortnight of Vaishaka month (Vaishakha Shukla Paksha Tritiya), is celebrated as Akshaya Tritiya.

[This answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/2188/17833), citing Wikipedia, claims that Vishnu took the form of [Hayagriva](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hayagriva) (the horse-headed deity) on the Akshaya Tritiya.

Further, [this magazine](https://www.google.co.in/books/edition/Kasturi_e_magazine/srHfDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&pg=PA17&printsec=frontcover), besides numerous other sources claim that Vishnu manifested as the famous [Nara-Narayana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nara-Narayana) rishis on the tithi of Akshaya-Tritiya.

**Does anywhere in the canonical text it is stated that Vishnu manifested as Hayagriva, and Nara-Narayana rishi, on the tithi of Akshaya-Tritiya?**

Answer (score 1):

lord prahalada asks a boon to god narasimha, after killing king hiranyakashipu, to stay at Simhachalam aka simhagiri,simhadri,simhashailam,as both varaha and narasimha avatars combined. god varaha kills king hiranyaksha and god narasimha kills king hiranyakashipu. both the kings being family members( father and fathers brother) of prahalada, he asks boon to the god to stay at simhaachalam as combined avatars of lord varaha and narasimha. the day the god gave the boon to prahalada and took avatar as varahanarasimha was on vaishaka shukla tritiya. every year devotees can witness nijaroopam of the swayanbhu vigraham of lord varahanarasimha on simhaachalam for three days starting from akshaya thritiya. this festival is called as chandanotsavam. as per narasimha purana and sthalapurana